# Avoiding raw types in Java message dispatcher

Tags: java, generics, dynamic-proxy, raw-types

### Objective

I am trying to build a MessageDispatcher that converts messages from a 3rd party API in to user defined messages and then dispatches them to a user registered listener.

The user will be expected to:

1. Define an interface for each type of user message.
2. Register a listener with the message dispatcher for each message type.
3. Pass raw/3rd party data in to the message dispatcher.
4. Handle messages passed back to listeners.

### Problem Description

Unfortunately I can't seem to avoid using a raw type to achieve my desired API.  I read elsewhere that there are no exceptional cases for using Raw types and they only exist in the language for backwards compatibility.

Is there a way I can change the code below to work or do I need to re-design my API?

### Interfaces

The MessageDispatcher implements the following interface:

```
public interface MessageDispatcher {

    // Register a listener for a given user defined message type.
    public <T> void registerListener(
        Class<T> messageClass, 
        MessageListener<T> listener);

    // Receive data in 3rd party format, convert and dispatch.
    public void onData(Data data);

}
```

The MessageListener interface is defined as:

```
public interface MessageListener<T> {

    public void onMessage(T message);   

}
```

An example user messages might look like this:

```
public interface MyMessage {

    public String getName();   

}
```

### Registering Listeners

The user can register a listener as follows:

```
messageDispatcher.registerListener(MyMessage.class, 
    new MessageListener<MyMessage.class>() {
    @Override

   public void onMessage(MyMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + message.getName());
    }
}
```

A standard message dispatcher might implement the method like this:

```
private Map<Class<?>,MessageListener<?>> messageClassToListenerMap;

public <T> void registerListener(
    Class<T> messageClass, 
    MessageListener<T> listener) {

    messageClassToListenerMap.put(messageClass, listener);

    // SNIP: Process the messageClass and extract the information needed
    // for creating dynamic proxies elsewhere in a proxy factory.

}
```

### Dispatching Messages

When a new message is received by the MessageDispatcher it creates a dynamic proxy for the object and dispatches it to an appropriate listener.  But this is where my problem is:

```
public void onData(Data data) {

    // SNIP: Use proxy factory (not shown) to get message class and
    // dynamic proxy object appropriate to the 3rd party data.
    Class<?> messageClass;  // e.g. = MyMessage.class;
    Object dynamicProxy;    // e.g. = DynamicProxy for MyMessage.class;

    // TODO: How to I pick the appropriate MessageListener and dispatch the
    // dynamicProxy in a type safe way?  See below.

}
```

If I try and use the type I can't dispatch the data:

```
// Assuming a listener has been registered for the example:
MessageListener<?> listener = messageClassToListenerMap.get(messageClass);

listener.onMessage(dynamicProxy); // ERROR: can't accept Object.
listener.onMessage(messageClass.cast(dynamicProxy); // ERROR: Wrong capture.
```

It makes sense, because there's no way I can know what type of data my listener accepts and what type of data I am passing it.

But if I use raw types it works fine:

```
// Assuming a listener has been registered for the example:
MessageListener listener = messageClassToListenerMap.get(messageClass);  
listener.onMessage(dynamicProxy); // OK, provided I always pass the correct type of object.
```

Comment: Without the generic interface the code would look something like: `messageDispatcher.registerListener(MyMessage.class, new MessageListener() { public void onMessage(Object data) { MyMessage msg = (MyMessage)data; // Do something with msg });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use raw types -- just cast the wildcarded types into a type that does what you want. This kinda flies in the face of type safety. And it will give an unchecked cast warning, which you can ignore. But it proves that it's possible to not use raw types.

```
MessageListener<Object> listener = (MessageListener<Object>)messageClassToListenerMap.get(messageClass);

listener.onMessage(dynamicProxy);
```

Comment: Yes, I guess I've taken up the responsibility of type safety within my library code however I should have all the necessary information to make that judgement.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use generics here, because exact type is known only at run-time, so you have to use unsafe cast. Raw types don't check types, hence it works. Generics works only in compile time, your dispatcher works in run time.

So, you should explicitly check it:

```
MessageListener listener = messageClassToListenerMap.get(messageClass);  
if(!messageClass.isAssignableFrom(dynamicProxy.getClass()))
  throw new Something();
listener.onMessage(dynamicProxy);
```

I think it's wrong design. I would recommend do something like that:

```
interface MyMessageListener
{
  void onMessageA(String name);
  void onMessageB(String otherParam);
}
```

when you could dispatch messages by the interface class and method name. (you could use interfaces with single method, but not so nice imho).
Moreover, the Spring already has infrastructure for it: `MethodInterceptor`, `RemoteExporter`, `RemoteInvocation` and some related.

Comment: Makes sense, the type information has been erased.  I don't really understand your recommendation though;  Messages are typically 10-200 fields of various types and when a new one appears the listener will want all the information.  I thought of onMessage as "Hey listener, here's some object that you can access with the interface you defined that contains all the data for your message"

Comment: @Karle you could have a method parameter as complex serializable object, such as   void `onMessageC(String simpleParam, ComplexObjectWith200Fields obj1, SimpleObjectWithOnly10Fields obj2);`. I think it looks more natural and you don't need create bunch of classes for simple things. Also it allows naturally compose related messages in one interface instead of bunch of unrelated classes. Also, you could use interface inheritance.

Comment: If you remember OOP basics, the method call is an equivalent of message passing: "In OOP, each object is capable of receiving messages, processing data, and sending messages to other objects." (c) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 0):

i have a trubble when i see you code , why do you use the proxy for you message class ... the message is just a java bean to sign a message event had happen , you just tell the listener that , there is a some type message had happen , you should do something to have do a listener's role ... this is a message's role .... i don't konw why there is a proxy for message , it so surprise......

Comment: The dynamic proxy provides an implementation of the interface the user has defined.  The interface will typically include annotations which help the proxy convert from the 3rd party data format to the users interface.